# How do I sort an array of strings given an arbitrary ordering of those strings?

Tags: perl, hash, sorting

I wish to sort an array of strings so that the strings wind up in the following order:

```
@set = ('oneM', 'twoM', 'threeM', 'sixM', 'oneY', 'twoY', 'oldest');
```

As you may notice, these represent time periods so `oneM` is the first month, etc.  My problem is that I want to sort by the time period, but with the strings as they are I can't just use 'sort', so I created this hash to express how the strings should be ordered:

```
my %comparison = (
    oneM    => 1,
    twoM    => 2,
    threeM  => 3,
    sixM    => 6,
    oneY    => 12,
    twoY    => 24,
    oldest  => 25,
);
```

This I was hoping would make my life easier where I can do something such as:

```
foreach my $s (@set) {
    foreach my $k (%comparison) {
        if ($s eq $k) {
            something something something
```

I'm getting the feeling that this is a long winded way of doing things and I wasn't actually sure how I would actually sort it once I've found the equivalent... I think I'm missing my own plot a bit so any help would be appreciated

As requested the expected output would be like how it is shown in @set above. I should have mentioned that the values in @set will be part of that set, but not necessarily all of them and not in the same order.

Comment: why does it always parse out the hello at the beginning of my post is a good question to add on ;(

Comment: because this is Q&A database, not a forum or mailing list.

Comment: doesn't mean I can't be friendly :)

Comment: Sure, but imagine encyclopedia starting every article with "Hello! Let me tell you about <subject>..." :)

Comment: and why not?! would be more interesting to read :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've choose good strategy in precomputing data to form easy to sort. You can calculate this data right inside sorting itself, but then you'd be wasting time for recalculation each time `sort` needs to compare value, which happens more than once through process. On the other hand, the drawback of cache is, obviously, that you'd need additional memory to store it and it might slow down your sort under low memory condition, despite doing less calculations overall.

With your current set up sorting is as easy as:

```
my @sorted = sort { $comparison{$a} <=> $comaprison{$b} } @set;
```

While if you want to save memory at expense of CPU it'd be:

```
my @sorted = sort { calculate_integer_based_on_input{$a} <=> calculate_integer_based_on_input{$b} } @set;
```

with separate `calculate_integer_based_on_input` function that would convert `oneY` and the like to `12` or other corresponding value on the fly or just inline conversion of input to something suitable for sorting.

You might also want to check out common idioms for sorting with caching computations, like [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) and [Guttman Rosler Transform](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=145659).

Comment: very useful - saving memory is always a good thing, much appreciated :)

Comment: Also the `sort_by` function from `List::UtilsBy`. This can simplify the above into simply   sort_by { calculate_integer_based_on_input($_) } @set
This is an abstraction of the Schwartzian transform

Answer (score 5):

Giving an example with the input and you expected result would help. I guess that this is what you are looking for:

```
my @data = ( ... ); 
my %comparison = (
    oneM   =>  1, twoM =>  2, threeM =>  3, 
    sixM   =>  6, oneY => 12, twoY   => 24,
    oldest => 25,
);

my @sorted = sort { $comparison{$a} <=> $comaprison{$b} } @data;
```

There are plenty of examples in the documentation for the `sort`function in the perlfunc manual page. ("perldoc -f sort")

Comment: thanks, I did look at several examples, but obviously didn't understand the application in this instance.